# Image field titles on <a> tags in Drupal 7

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, fancybox

I created a content type for an image gallery. It has an image field where I browse for the image file and I can define Alternate text and Title. The result looks somtehing like this:

```
<a href="image.jpg">
    <img src="image_thumb.jpg" title="my image title" alt="my image alt text" />
</a>
```

I am implementing Fancybox gallery. When I click on an image, gallery opens, but I don't see the title because Fancybox jQuery script takes the title attribute from  tags to display. Drupal puts it in  tags.

How can I make Fancybox look for the title attribute in  tags?
I tried to modify the jquery script, but it's too complicated for me.

Can Drupal display the code like this:

```
 <a href="image.jpg" title="my image title">
    <img src="image_thumb.jpg" title="my image title" alt="my image alt text" />
</a>
```

**UPDATE**

I found a solution: in **jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js** on line 93

```
title = selectedOpts.orig.attr('alt');
```

just replaced 'alt' with 'title'  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change line 86 with this.
  this version adds another condition witch fits your needs

```
title = selectedOpts.title || (obj.nodeName ? $(obj).attr('title') : obj.title) || $(obj).children("img").attr("title") ||'';
```